Calculating gigaton range blast wave properties
One of the biggest arguments against large nuclear devices is that most of the energy escapes into space. My limited understanding is that this happens because when the shockwave is still in the embryonic phase (being driven by the bubble of expanding hot air), the low atmospheric density at the top causes the bubble to vent upwards.
I have found programs that can calculate the the properties of a small ground burst. But is there any way to scale the results to the large, asteroid level blasts?
Suppose we input some large megatonnage (1000+) into the above calculator, and got the results for blast wave at ground level. We know it is overestimating, but how much? Is there any equation or rule of thumb that can be used to scale the overpressure, impulse, time, etc to their correct values?
Or even better, is there some program than directly compute the properties at ground level given a yield?

One reason this question may not have gotten any answers is that it is unclear whether it is asking about the blast wave from an "asteroid impact" or an "asteroid level" nuclear explosion. The title uses the former while the question refers to the latter.  The physics of asteroid impacts and nuclear blasts are related but are not identical.  If the question is about nuclear explosions, it might be better to give the megatonnage range of interest, since "asteroid level" runs from zero to mass extinction events.  More references might also help, e.g. about how large blasts are vented to space.
